# Is there a properties limit?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am planning on building my solution, using massive amounts of properties.
Is there a limit how many properties can an entity have?
Which way is better, to divide the data into more kinds or fewer kinds and many properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Datastore limits here.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits

Here it is said, that single entity can have up to 20000 of indexed properties. If you would like to not index them, then probably you can get even higher number of properties in an entity, but you will be limited by 1Mb limit of overall entity size.

Splitting on several kinds or using one highly depends on you task.